# Apply a command for each file in bin_SCRIPTS using Automake

Tags: c++, bash, autotools, automake, m4

In my project, I have a set of bash scripts that are copied along with the C/C++ binaries to the installation root.

The problem is that I have to run a command for each of those BASH scripts before they are installed. To be more concrete I have to substitute a variable with an autoconf output variable:

```
 anyfile sed 's/ECLIPSE_PATH/@prefix@/g'
```

Here is where the scripts are defined in the Makefile.am

```
 bin_SCRIPTS = file1.sh file2.sh
```

I wonder if there is any standard way to deal with this. If not I would like to come with some hack to deal with it. Thanks!

#### UPDATE

I came up with a hack to solve it, here is the Automake recipe:

```
install-data-hook:
  input_path="@prefix@";                          \
  path=$${input_path//\//\\/};                    \
  for i in @bindir@/*; do                         \
    if [[ ! `file $${i}` =~ "ELF" ]]; then        \                                                                                                                                                                  
      sed -i "s/\$$ECLIPSE_PATH/$${path}/g" $$i;  \
    fi                                            \
  done
```

But I still wonder whether there is a standard way to do it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Substituting autoconf-discovered variables into a script is indeed a normal thing to do.  It's typically done using `AC_CONFIG_FILES`.

The most normal way to do it is to give your source file a `.in` suffix, and then rewrite to `.sh` using autoconf.  Something like:

```
AC_CONFIG_FILES([script.sh:script.in], [chmod +x script.sh])
```

Then in the source file, just write `@whatever@`, instead of using `ECLIPSE_PATH`.

Now, I realize you wanted to do it at install time.  But, normally that is the wrong approach.  In the auto* world it isn't really ok to change `prefix` between configure and install time -- you must reconfigure.

If you really want to do it at install time then I think your approach is nearly reasonable enough.  Looping over the contents of `bindir` is dangerous for users of your package -- what if they are installing it into a tree with other programs?  It's better, IMO, to loop over `$(bin_SCRIPTS)`.

Comment: Do you happen to know what the `autoconf` version support for that format of arguments to `AC_CONFIG_FILES` is (is it recent or is it effectively "all")?

Comment: Such a good answer. Just thought I'd add a link to the [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf.html#Configuration-Files).

Comment: Really good anwser.  It made me understand a bit more of autotool. Thanks :)

Comment: Also can I use a wildcard as a  AC_CONFIG_FILES argument? I have to process around 15 files

Comment: I don't think you can use a wildcard.  You could probably write a looping m4 macro though.

Comment: @TomTromey I found out that you are the main contributor for automake project. Is great to get answers from the maintainer of automake:D

Comment: One more question, how can I specify that new file (generated from the *.in template) to be installed when 'make install'

Comment: I used to be the main contributor but I haven't worked on it in many years.  To make the file be installed, just list in `bin_SCRIPTS` as usual.